# replace the string with dynamic alphanumeric characters using regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

Suppose I have a file which have one string value along with dynamic alphanumeric characters .
So I need to replace the string with null characters .

String :

> preso1DA7B5FB-01B4-8AB8-B8B2-93B7118ED92B

Here preso will be always constant and other alphanumeric characters will keep on changing (Dynamic value).

How to write regex expression for string 
My regex is :

> preso.*?\n

public class PatternSearchAndReplace {

```
public String replaceWithPattern(String str,String replace){

    Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("(?<=preso).*");
    Matcher mtch = ptn.matcher(str);
    return mtch.replaceAll(replace);
}

public static void main(String a[]){
    String str = "Hello_preso1D88B7B3-FE77-7A3D-9758-C3820B6D83FB/cfslideshow.js";
    PatternSearchAndReplace mpr = new PatternSearchAndReplace();
    System.out.println(mpr.replaceWithPattern(str, " "));
}
```

}

Output I wanted is : Hello_/cfslideshow.js

Comment: what do you want to have output?

Comment: Hi Akash,
Search for string preso1DA7B5FB-01B4-8AB8-B8B2-93B7118ED92B in file and replace with null space .
Example :
My dynamic is preso1DA7B5FB-01B4-8AB8-B8B2-93B7118ED92B and replace with My dynamic id is .

Comment: @MK28 Answer the question please.

Comment: u can try as ^preso  . this will get you all the string starts with preso.

Comment: Hi Saranya,
^preso will replace the only preso character but not the dyanmic character which is fixed in length in string preso1DA7B5FB-01B4-8AB8-B8B2-93B7118ED92B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use *positive lookbehind*. I am assuming that you want to get dynamic alphanumberic character in given string :

i.e.

```
(?<=preso).*
```

Positive lookbehind is *zero length assertion* as it do not captures what it match and captures value which are after lookbehind expression

Looking at your updated post, you should capture all characters along with preso, so, your regex should be like this :

```
preso.*(?=/)
```

Comment: @downvoter : Care to comment?

Comment: Hi Akash, 
Still it is not giving what I wanted .
  String str = "Hello_preso1D88B7B3-FE77-7A3D-9758-C3820B6D83FB/slideshow.js";
Ouput : Hello_/slideshow.js

Comment: will there be always same format like /slideshow.j‌​s in the end?

Comment: if there is always `/` after dynamic alphanumeric content, then you can use : `preso.*(?=/)`

Comment: Akash, your answer worked for me .
Thanks !!!

Comment: Glad, it helped you!!! You can accept answer if it works for you !!!